# What should the value parameter look like when programmatically triggering a signal in Vega?

Tags: vega, vega-embed

In one of my view's layers I have

```
  "params": [
    {
      "name": "selectedFeature",
      "select": {
        "type": "point",
        "fields": ["order"]
      }
    }
```

I'm using `vega-embed` and added a signal listener.

```
vegaInstance.view.addSignalListener('selectedFeature', async function (signalName, e) {
    console.debug(signalName, JSON.stringify(e))
    // Returns e.g. 
    // selectedFeature {"order":[2],"vlPoint":{"or":[{"order":2}]}}
}
```

This works ok. But I would like to trigger the signal from outside of the chart too (without binding it to an element), like it is explained [in the View API docs](https://vega.github.io/vega/docs/api/view/#view_signal).

I tried things like

```
vegaInstance.view.signal('selectedFeature', {order: 2})
```

and

```
vegaInstance.view.signal('selectedFeature', {
    order: [2],
    vlPoint: {
        or: [{
            order: 2
        }]
    }
});
```

but no luck. The debug message log prints out

```
selectedFeature {}
```

meaning the signal `name` is being picked up, but not its `value`. What format should `value` be?

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by adding a hidden input field and binding the param to that input field. I then trigger an input event on that input field.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the same issue by updating the selection with vegaInstance.view.signal('selectedFeature**_tuple**', {...}) instead of vegaInstance.view.signal('selectedFeature', {...}). Got that from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59708383/programmatically-update-the-signal-for-a-multi-click-in-vega-vega-lite)